# This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode Error when using an ASP.NET Fileupload Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, umbraco

I have a simple page with an asp.net fileupload field on it.  Works fine on development machine but when deployed to server I get This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode error.

The site is running in integrated mode.

Any postback causes the error to fire.

The site is using telerik rad controls (but not on that page) and is running on windows server 2008 under the umbraco content management system.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checked the application pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a Telerik Rad Upload setting was present in the web-config file, despite this control not being needed (probably auto registered when dropping a control on the page).

Removed the settings and all worked ok.

Answer (score 2):

Switch website's app pool to Integrated Mode. You'll find pools in IIS manager.